# How much memory does the MySQL server variable table_open_cache cause the DBMS to use?

Tags: mysql, memory

Simple question, but I have been unable to find simple answers.

So the default value for the table_open_cache server variable is 2000. Which means 2000 slots for 2000 files. We can assume each slot takes a few bytes. As we are not discussing Table row data, but Table information. Perhaps 1K or memory each slot.

So, if we increase the cache size by a factor of 10, how much memory is then required by MySQL 5.7? And is the usage linear?

Comment: There is a good answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45551/how-to-optimize-table-cache

Comment: That link does not say how big each entry is.  Nor have I found such info.

Comment: About [this much](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/table_cache.h#L218-L246) but I'd stick to Rick's answer.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your contributions.

My focus here is not 'what is the best setting', but 'how much memory is the current setting using'.

Dan, thank you for that link. My Java is not nearly good enough to get a accurate byte value per slot. But, it seems to reinforce my perception that each slot takes just a few bytes.

Andrew G
DBA

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it from another point of view -- Is `table_open_cache` too big or too small?

If `Table_open_cache_overflows / Uptime` > 1 per second, then increase the setting.

If `Table_open_cache_misses / Uptime` > 1/sec, then increase `table_open_cache`

If `Table_open_cache_misses / (Table_open_cache_hits + Table_open_cache_misses) > 3%, then increase` table_open_cache`and check`table_open_cache_instances`.