# How MySQL Table cache hitrate should be calculated?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 5.7.15 instance which is monitored by nagios with [check_mysql_health](https://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_mysql_health/) plugin.

One of the metrics monitored is tablecache-hitrate which is triggering a critical alert. (hitrate ~50%)

My current table_open_cache value is the default of 2K.

My current GLOBAL stats are:

```
| Max_used_connections                          | 20      |
| Opened_tables                                 | 5278    |
| Open_tables                                   | 2000    |
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 803395  |
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 5278    |
| Table_open_cache_overflows                    | 3271    |
```

The UPTIME at the time of those status were:

Uptime:         20 days 22 hours 30 min 45 sec

My Current tables by storage engine:

```
+-----------------------+-----------+
|  engine               | count(*)  |
+-----------------------+-----------+
|    InnoDB             |   105     |
|    MEMORY             |   51      |
|    CSV                |   2       |
|    MyISAM             |   11      |
|    PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA |   87      |
|    NULL               |  115      |
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

That's 256 tables and 115 views. 371 items.

I have a cronjob that runs a whole mysqldump every saturday. I take a status variables on friday and on sunday. The values of last friday and monday are:

Friday:

```
| Max_used_connections                          | 20        |
| Open_tables                                   | 2000      |
| Opened_tables                                 | 4309      |
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 513027    |
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 4309      |
```

Monday:

```
| Max_used_connections                          | 20       |
| Open_tables                                   | 2000     |
| Opened_tables                                 | 4924     |
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 699751   |
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 4924     |
```

I've seen a couple of ways to calculate tablecache_hitrate:

1. Open_tables / Opened_tables
2. Table cache hit rate = table_open_cache*100/Opened_tables

With those approaches the table_cache_hitrate will lower as the uptime increases, because of new tables created, mysqldump the whole database (opening all tables), etc...

Q1. Does mysqldump bypass table_open_cache? Or it uses already cached tables?

So i think that they aren't a reliable way to calculate tablecache_hitrate.

I guess for MySQL 5.6.6+, it can be calculated based on Table_open_cache_hits and Table_open_cache_misses.

Q2. Is this correct? Or what would be the most accurate way to calculate table_open_cache hitrate?

Regards!

Comment: What was the Uptime when those `STATUS` values were grabbed?  (Or grab them again, plus `Uptime`.)

Comment: It should not be calculated at all.  Unless you are a MySQL developer, it's usually best to pretend that you've never heard of the open table cache, becauae it's a very delicate mechanism that will kill your performance if you try to optimize it.  See [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44892/11651) and [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45570/11651).  As a DBA, I've *never* had a good reason to change this, but more than one server from "before my time" was immediately cured of poor performance by removing configured values for this, and reverting to defaults.

Comment: so, should i disable that metric? i would not want to receive notifications of a metric that doesn't give me "important" information...

Answer (score 0):

I *could* be that the plugin is looking at deltas, and the dump had to open all the tables at least once, thereby running through the cache and getting a burst of "misses".

The "hits" are quite high relative to the other values, so I don't see a real 'problem'.  But you could increase `table_open_cache` and `table_open_cache_instances`.

What was `Max_used_connections`?  I *guess* that number was rather high, and the many connections were opening lots of tables, thereby reaching up to (and past) 2000.  Later, when the dump came along, many of the little-used tables had been bumped out of cache, hence a low hit rate.

Suggest you grab those `GLOBAL STATUS` readings before and after a dump.  This may (or may not) confirm my guesses.

Comment: The "per second" values are reasonably small; so, again, I am not worried about the numbers.  Perhaps most of the 615 "misses" were due to the dump.

Comment: Yes, i think so too.. so which would be the more accurate way to calculate tablecache_hitrate?

Comment: Are you hoping to modify the Nagios plugin?

Comment: I want to tune my DB correctly, i want to make sure that this value is being calculated properly so i can act accordingly... and yes, if we agree on a best way to calculate this value, i can make the comments and link to this question to the developer of the plugin...

Comment: Since you seem to have a burst of table opens when you do the dump, you _could_ increase `table_open_cache` until the problem goes away, or you _could_ ignore it during the dump (since it is relatively harmless).  Based on the numbers you have presented, I am not sure how to find the 'perfect' value for that setting.